# How to call winapi from java with jna

Tags: java, windows, jna

I want to be able to call all of the available winapi functions (or at least the most popular functions).

On jna, first you have to implement the interface of the DLL you want to use and then the prototypes of the functions.

Is there anything that might help me to be able to create a library that exports all of the available winapi functions?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe **Jawin** project can help you
http://sourceforge.net/projects/jawinproject/

Comment: Please provide a little moe context to your answer. While it might be obvious to some users, to others it might not...